# APEX 5 pass values from one page to another

Tags: oracle-apex

I work on APEX 5 application and have 2 pages. On page 10 there are a tree with Selected Node Page Item set to P10_ORG_ID (hidden), Item of type Select List called P10_PERIOD and button NEXT. What I want is when press button NEXT to go to page 11 and pass values of clicked node (:P10_ORG_ID) and selected value (:P10_PERIOD) to it.
How could I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way: 
add Redirect to Page 11 action to button NEXT assigning corresponding items, add Dynamic Action on Items P10_ORG_ID and P10_PERIOD Change event with Submit Page Action and add After Processing Branch of type Page or URL (Redirect) to the same page (Page 10) with those two Items set to persist values.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a button, you can chose its action ("Redirect to page in this application") In the button settings, you have the option to pass a list of names ("Set these items", comma separated list) and values ("With these values", comma separated list) to the page you go to. Just fill it in to make values available.

Comment: I already did this but when go to page 11, Items were populated with values from other values, session state was not populated with DOM state.

Comment: @dragy Sorry, I am not sure I understand you.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I click on some node on the tree and P10_ORG_ID is populated with that node value, then I select some period on Item P10_PERIOD and go to button NEXT. Application go to page 11 but values of page 11 Items  don't match with values from page 10 Items.

Comment: @dragy no, but they are accessible. You can even see them in your address bar if you run the application. Figure out how to extract them!

Comment: Probably I do something wrong. But, in address bar I can see only P10_PERIOD with value, P10_ORG_ID is null. I also tried with Page Items to Submit but with no success. Anyway, I did it this way: add Redirect to Page 11 action to button NEXT, add Dynamic Action on Items P10_ORG_ID and P10_PERIOD Change with Submit Page Action and add After Processing Branch of Type Page or URL (Redirect) to the same page (Page 10) with those two Items set to persist values. Only this combination works for me. Thank you.